# how to Solution This browser or app may not be secure in python selenium

Tags: authentication

[image]

I have a problem to login Google because of the problem that claims that the browser is not secure, is there a solution I have tried using Firefox and Chrome but it don't works

Answer (score 0):

Try undetected chromedriver

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver
```